# Build nested JSON from string of nested keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have csv files that I am reading using nodeJS. I convert each file to text before reading.

Each line in the file have data delimited with `=`.

Each line looks something like

```
data.location.degree.text=sometexthere
```

The first portion before the "=" represents an index to a JSON object in my app. My aim is to parse this data and build a JSON representation of it so that the line above becomes

```
data:{
  location:{
    degree:{
      text: 'sometexthere'
    }
  }
}
```

Using javascript/nodejs; How can I convert a string which is supposed to represent a sequence of nested JSON keys, into a JSON object like above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could split the path and make a check if the following element exist. If not assign an object to the new property.

Return then the value of the property.

At the end assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    path = path.replace(/[\[]/gm, '.').replace(/[\]]/gm, ''); //to accept [index]
    var keys = path.split('.'),
        last = keys.pop();

    keys.reduce(function (o, k) { return o[k] = o[k] || {}; }, object)[last] = value;
}

var data = {};

setValue(data, 'location.degree.text', 'sometexthere');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: this is elegant as ****!

Comment: @Nina Scholz I would give this a thousands thumbs up if I could. Thanks!

Comment: add `path = path.replace(/[\[]/gm, '.').replace(/[\]]/gm, '');` to the top of the function to accept `[n]` parameter. `.0` and `[0]` both work the same

Comment: @SwiftNinjaPro, that is right, but an edit makes in view of the question no sense.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// result container
var res = {};

// input data
var inp = [
    'data.location.degree.text=sometexthere',
    'data.otherLocation.degree.otherText=foo',
    'data.location.degree.otherText=bar',
    'we.can.handle.values.that.are_undefined=',
    'we.can.handle.values.that.contain_equals_signs=yes=we=can'
];

// recursive function
var pathToObject = function(resultReference, path)
{
    // split path on dots
    // e.g. data.location.degree.text=sometexthere
    // -> ["data", "location", "degree", "text=sometexthere"]
    var splitPathParts = path.split('.');

    // if there is only one part, we're at the end of our path expression
    // e.g. ["text=sometexthere"]
    if (splitPathParts.length === 1){
        // split "text=sometexthere" into ["text", "sometexthere"]
        var keyAndValue = splitPathParts[0].split('=');

        // set foo = bar on our result object reference
        resultReference[keyAndValue.shift()] = keyAndValue.join('=');
        return;
    }
  
    // the first element of the split array is our current key
    // e.g. for ["data", "location", "degree", "text=sometexthere"],
    // the currentKey would be "data";
    var currentKey = splitPathParts.shift();

    // if our object does not yet contain the current key, set it to an empty object
    resultReference[currentKey] || (resultReference[currentKey] = {});
    
    // recursively call ourselves, passing in
    // the nested scope and the rest of the path.
    // e.g. { data : {} } and 'location.degree.text=sometexthere'
    pathToObject(resultReference[currentKey], splitPathParts.join('.'));
}

for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++)
{
    pathToObject(res, inp[i]);
}
console.log(res);
```

ES6 syntax makes things slightly more terse:

```js
'use strict';

const pathToObject = (resultReference, path) => {
  let [currentKey, ...restOfPath] = path.split('.');
  
  if (restOfPath.length === 0) {
    let [k, ...v] = currentKey.split('=');
    resultReference[k] = v.join('=');
    return;
  }

  resultReference[currentKey] || (resultReference[currentKey] = {});
  pathToObject(resultReference[currentKey], restOfPath.join('.'));
}

let res = {};

[
  'data.location.degree.text=sometexthere',
  'data.otherLocation.degree.otherText=foo',
  'data.location.degree.otherText=bar',
  'we.can.handle.values.that.are_undefined=',
  'we.can.handle.values.that.contain_equals_signs=yes=we=can'
].forEach(x => pathToObject(res, x));

console.log(res);
```